# creating a list of dataframes => warning:In df_list[i] <- as.data.frame(df_ex) : number of items to replace is not a multiple of replacement length

Tags: r

I am trying to generate a list of dataframes , it worked with a list of numeric(1), for a list of vectors i had to convert them into dataframes to be accepted by the list. But for dataframes the pre-allocated list won't be accepted for storage and the warning as shown in the title( sry console language german)   is returned.
Here is the code :

```
>num_vec <- numeric(3)

# 2) save vector to list : 

> vec_list <- vector ( mode= "list", length=length(num_vec))
> str(vec_list)
List of 3
 $ : NULL
 $ : NULL
 $ : NULL
> #vec_list
> 
> for ( i in 1 : length(vec_list)){
+ 
+  vec_list[i] <- as.data.frame(rnorm(2))
+ }
> 
> vec_list
[[1]]
[1]  0.3627056 -0.6183881

[[2]]
[1] 0.65133882 0.05740896

[[3]]
[1] -0.3975722  0.4564257

> 
> 
> 
> # 
> 
> # 3 ) save dataframe to list : 
> 
> 
> 
> df_list <- vector(mode = "list", length=length(num_vec))
> str(df_list)
List of 3
 $ : NULL
 $ : NULL
 $ : NULL
> #df_list
> 
> df_ex <- data.frame(num_vec,letters[1:length(num_vec)])
> df_ex
  num_vec letters.1.length.num_vec..
1       0                          a
2       0                          b
3       0                          c
> str(df_list[1])
List of 1
 $ : NULL
> str(df_ex)
'data.frame':   3 obs. of  2 variables:
 $ num_vec                   : num  0 0 0
 $ letters.1.length.num_vec..: chr  "a" "b" "c"
> 
> for ( i in 1: length(df_list)){
+   
+   df_list[i] <- as.data.frame(df_ex)
+  
+   
+ }
Warnmeldungen:
1: In df_list[i] <- as.data.frame(df_ex) :
  Anzahl der zu ersetzenden Elemente ist kein Vielfaches der Ersetzungslänge
2: In df_list[i] <- as.data.frame(df_ex) :
  Anzahl der zu ersetzenden Elemente ist kein Vielfaches der Ersetzungslänge
3: In df_list[i] <- as.data.frame(df_ex) :
  Anzahl der zu ersetzenden Elemente ist kein Vielfaches der Ersetzungslänge
> 
> df_list
[[1]]
[1] 0 0 0

[[2]]
[1] 0 0 0

[[3]]
[1] 0 0 0
```

So the list restricts dimensions of possible inputs? what kind of object do i have to create that accepts dataframes ?

I've looked similar questions, and I did not find an answer that would work for me. Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: if you use double brackets does it work as expected? eg `df_list[[i]]` In R double brackets will access the list element, the single brackets will return a subsetted list (but still a list), so you usually want the double brackets for adding/updating a list element like this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not quite sure I understand what you want in the dataframes in your list of dataframes, but as @Nate points out in the comments `df_list[[i]]` is wanted.  Hopefully this example will help...

```r
num_vec <- numeric(3)

df_list <- vector ( mode= "list", length=length(num_vec))
str(df_list)
#> List of 3
#>  $ : NULL
#>  $ : NULL
#>  $ : NULL

for ( i in 1:length(df_list)){
  df_list[[i]] <- data.frame(numb_vec = num_vec,
                             x = rnorm(length(num_vec)), 
                             y = letters[1:length(num_vec)])
 }

df_list
#> [[1]]
#>   numb_vec          x y
#> 1        0 -0.4198877 a
#> 2        0 -1.0098846 b
#> 3        0  0.7443170 c
#> 
#> [[2]]
#>   numb_vec          x y
#> 1        0 -1.5222796 a
#> 2        0 -1.3661836 b
#> 3        0  0.7935504 c
#> 
#> [[3]]
#>   numb_vec          x y
#> 1        0 -1.1877873 a
#> 2        0  0.3398783 b
#> 3        0  1.3145989 c
```

Comment: the double brackets! thank you and @nate it's working !